How to apply a function to a number of variables in the same dataframe?
I wrote the following function and I would like to apply it to a number of variables in my dataset.
Here is the function I wrote:
fun <- function(data, var_1) {

var_1 <- enquo(var_1)

prop_all <- data %>%
filter(!!var_1>=0)%>%
group_by(!!var_1)%>%
summarise(Percent=round(survey_mean(vartype="ci")*100,0), 
          Total = unweighted(n()))

prop_sex <-data %>%
filter(!!var_1>=0 & Sex>=0)%>%
group_by(Sex, !!var_1)%>%
summarise(Percent=round(survey_mean(vartype="ci")*100,0), 
          Total = unweighted(n()))

prop_final <- bind_rows(prop_all, prop_sex)

and here I call the function:
prop <- fun(data=df, var_1=alc)

This produces figures only for alc and I was wondering how I can apply this function to a number of variables in my dataset and produce a data frame that will include figures for all indicators.

Please take a look at dplyr:;across.  If you can't figure out what to do, please supply a minimal reproducible example so that we can give you concrete advice.  Your MRE should include both test input data and the output you expect from that data.

The way you wrote the function makes it that you only can run it for a single variable, so you would have to rewrite it in order to be run for many variables.
Another option would be running your function inside a for loop, map, or apply, so that you can run the same function many times using different arguments (in this case, variables).
Using purrr::map:
variables = c("als", "var2", "var3", "var4")
props <- map(variables, ~fun(df, .x))

This would result in a list that contains all the dataframes for the variables provided in variables. You would have to modify your function sightly to make it run using a string of the variable name by changing var_1 <- enquo(var_1) to var_1 <- sym(var_1).
But I can't test this answer because you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example!
